# Front end servers return themselves as visiting host

Tags: apache, nginx, proxy, tornado

I have tested quite a few front end proxies like HAProxy, Apache, Nginx and Lighttpd but in my logs on my tornado backend servers I am just getting visited by the front end server. Meaning, I would like to know the real ip from the client that is visiting, so my log analyzer thinks I am getting more visits than 1.

What would be the simplest way to do this ?

Backend is tornado python, frontend could be any of the above, but I currently have nginx configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options. The easiest to implement is simply consume the x-forwarded-for header:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For

To enable x-forwarded-for in haproxy simply add:

option forwardfor

http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.4.html#4.2-option%20forwardfor

If you do not want to consume the x-forwarded-for header then you can try to push having the "PROXY protocol" implemented in tornado or look at using something like gunicorn. http://gunicorn.org/ . The PROXY protocol works by adding the original L4 information to the end of the L7 data. The receiving server must understand the PROXY protocol or it just looks like a corrupt packet.